# Is there a real matrix such that $B^2=A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Is there a real matrix $3 \times 3$ Matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$ where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0& 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have written $A$ as

$$A=C-I$$  where

$$C=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  0& 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

So $$B^2+I=C$$ and obviously

$$Det(B^2+I)=0$$

Any help here?

Comment: The matrix $J_{2 \times 2} = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ works as the imaginary number. Try yourself to square it. The matrix $A$ is a block matrix $\left(\begin{matrix} 1_{1 \times 1} & 0_{1 \times 2} \\ 0_{2 \times 1} & -1_{2 \times 2}\end{matrix}\right)$ and can be written as $\left(\begin{matrix} 1_{1 \times 1} & 0_{1 \times 2} \\ 0_{2 \times 1} & J_{2 \times 2}\end{matrix}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT Use Cayley Hamilton theorem. You have $B^2=A$ and $B^3=AB$. Also $\det(B)=\pm 1$